# Limit of $\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I don't understand the rewriting that's being done in this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1−\cos x}{\sin x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} $$

Why doesn't this simplify to $\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}$?

Comment: L'Hopitals Rule.

Comment: and $\sin x/\sin x = 1$ whereas the original limit is $0$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to see how to use MathJax on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. You can use [l'Hospital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to get
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \tan 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

rewrite it as $$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$$

Comment: It's a good idea to find the value of the limit, but it boils down to $\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$ which is something that the OP got

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)}=\tan(x/2).$$

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is
$$\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{1-\cos x}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}=\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$$